# Thermodynamics problem for school

Tags: thermodynamics

I will try to translate it as best as I can

T = temperature

Pi = P initial

Vf = V final

Monoatomic  gas

The T doubles isobarically (process 1-2), absorbing heat Q12=250 J.
The gas is then cooled isocorically (process 2-3) until the T is equal to the initial T.

Calculate:

Q31, Delta U31, W31, if the system is brought to the initial state through an isothermal process. (process 3-1)

I calculated the values for the 12 and 23 processes:

Q12 = 250J

W12 = 100J

Delta U12 = 150J

Q23 = -150J

W23 = 0J

Delta U23 = -150J

Here's what I calculated to try and get closer to the answer:

Delta U = n Cv Delta T => Delta U = n Cv Tinitial = 150J

Using Delta U = n Cv Tinitial = 150J, I calculated:

n Cv Tinitial = 150J

n 3/2R Ti = 150J

nRTi 3/2 = 150J

nRTi = 100 J

So then I tried to use it for the isothermal formula for Q.

Using these two formulas:

Q31 = nRTi ln(Vf/Vi) (isothermal)

Q31 = 100 ln(1/2)

Q31 = -69,314.

But the book says that Q31 = -115J. I don't understand how they got that answer.
Here's the graph I came up with:
[image: this is the graph that I came up with]

Answer (score 1):

This is too late for your homework assignment, but for what it's worth, I got the exact same answers as you listed in your post for each process. Not sure where the book solution comes from.